# adding objects to list if it doesn't contain it

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to add object to a list only if it wasn't added already .. like this:

```
  for (var interest in poll.poll.interests) {
        InterestDrop n = new InterestDrop(interest, false);
        print(interest);
        print(dropInterestsList);
        print(dropInterestsList.contains(n));
        if (!(dropInterestsList.contains(n))){
          dropInterestsList.add(n);

        }
      }
```

but this always return false and add the object even when its already there ... how to solve this?

**ANSWER:**

```
class InterestDrop {
String name;
bool isClicked;

InterestDrop(this.name, this.isClicked);

bool operator == (o) => o is InterestDrop && name == o.name && isClicked == o.isClicked;
int get hashCode => hash2(name.hashCode, isClicked.hashCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the [equality operator](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) in your custom class.

From the docs:

> The default behavior for all Objects is to return true if and only if
>   this and other are the same object.

So your contains method will only return true if your array contains the exact object you are comparing against.

Comment: aha i see!! can you please give me an example of how to override the equality operator in your custom class?

Comment: You can follow @Siavash's answer. Once you add that method to your class and make sure it compares the correct properties, it should just work.

Comment: You will also want to override the [hashCode](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) property.

Comment: can you please check my updated post .. i did this but i got an error .. also i don't know how to override the hashCode? can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
class InterestDrop {
  operator ==(InterestDrop other) => identifier == other.identifier;
}
```

Comment: and then how to use it?